# how can know ssh is disconected and retry with bash script

Tags: bash, ssh, reverse

I'm using reverse ssh for connecting to remote client , Operator run reverse one time and leave client system 
how can i write bash script , when reverse ssh disconnected from server retry to connect to server (ssh)

Comment: Did you mean "Reverse SSH Tunneling"?

Comment: Sometimes an SSH session can appear to "hang" with the process failing to disappear.  It sounds like you want a sort of "watchdog" that will test for a *function* tunnel, rather than just check to make sure the process still exists.  There are a number of ways to do that, which you can research.  If you have trouble implementing one, please ask a question showing the code you've tried, along with your expected and actual results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/).  Autossh "automatically restart[s] SSH sessions and tunnels"

```
sudo apt-get install autossh
```

I use autossh to to keep open reverse tunnel that I depend on.  It works very well, even with long periods of lost connection.

Here is the script I use to create the tunnel:

```
#!/bin/bash
AUTOSSH_GATETIME=0
export AUTOSSH_GATETIME
autossh -f -N -R 8022:localhost:22 username@host -o "ServerAliveInterval 45" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 2"
```

I execute this script at boot with this cronjob:

```
@reboot /home/scripts/./persistent-tunnel.sh
```

Comment: Apparently `AUTOSSH_GATETIME` is set to 0 if you use `-f`, so I don't think you need it.

Answer (score 7):

If you simply want to retry a command until it succeeds, you can use this pattern:

```
while ! ssh [...]
do
    echo "Command failed, retrying..." >&2
done
```

Comment: Thank for this answer. It's a very simple implementation :)

Answer (score 2):

I have a slightly different method.
My method always tries to reconnect you if you have a dirty disconnection: '~.' or 'Connection closed by remote host.'
But if you disconnect with 'CRTL+D' or with 'exit' it just disconnects and show you some info of the connections.

```
#/bin/bash  
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
        echo '''
        Please also provide ssh connection details.
        '''
        exit 1
fi  
retries=0
repeat=true
today=$(date)  
while "$repeat"
do
        ((retries+=1)) &&
        echo "Try number $retries..." &&
        today=$(date) &&
        ssh "$@" &&
        repeat=false
        sleep 5
done  
echo """
        Disconnected sshx after a successful login.
        Total number of tries = $retries
        Connected at:
        $today
"""
```

Comment: Apologies for the duplicated text, just realised it. 

Anyways, save that to your ~/.bin folder with name sshx 
And source that folder in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile

Than just use sshx to connect rather then ssh. 

To help a little bit more, the main function in on these lines:

- ssh "$@" && repeat=false - 

This will get all the args passed to sshx and forward them as an ssh command, and only if the ssh command exists successfully with a 0 the variable will be set to false and the loop broken. Otherwise it continues trying to run the ssh command. 

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look into ssh options ServerAliveInterval, ServerAliveCountMax and TCPKeepAlive because sometimes your line dies without making this obvious, let me demonstrate:

```
#!/bin/sh

while true; do

ssh -T user@host \
  -o IdentityFile=~/.ssh/tunnel \
  -o UserKnownHostsFile=~/.ssh/known_hosts.tunnel \
  pkill -f "^sshd:\ user\ \ \ \ $" # needs to be edited for nearly every case

sleep 2

ssh -T -N user@host \
  -o IdentityFile=~/.ssh/tunnel \
  -o UserKnownHostsFile=~/.ssh/known_hosts.tunnel \
  -o Batchmode=yes \
  -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes \
  -o ServerAliveCountMax=1 \
  -o ServerAliveInterval=60 \
  -o LocalForward=127.0.0.1:2501=127.0.0.1:25 \
  -o RemoteForward=127.0.0.1:2501=127.0.0.1:25

sleep 60

done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `netstat -ntp | grep ":22"` or `ss -ntp | grep ":22"` to see established connections to ssh port, then use grep to filter the ip address you're looking for. If you don't find a connection then reconnect the tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

Use autossh if it works on your version of Linux. It did not on mine as it was an outdated Linux distribution for a custom NAS box.

The alternative is a simple bash script in crontab like this:

**maintain_reverse_ssh_tunnel.sh**

`if ! netstat -planet |grep myserver_ip_or_name |grep ESTABLISHED > /dev/null; then
    echo "REVERSE SSH DOWN - Restarting the tunnels"
    ssh -fN -R 32999:localhost:22 -R 28080:localhost:80 myusername@myserver_ip_or_name
fi`

Replace `myusername` and `myserver_ip_or_name` with those of your user and server.

Then add an entry to crontab by typing `crontab -e` and adding the following line:

`1 * * * * /path_to_my_script/maintain_reverse_ssh_tunnel.sh`

Make sure to have the execute permissions on the script:

`chmod 755 maintain_reverse_ssh_tunnel.sh`